# Git URL Structure

Tags: regex, git, github

I am trying to build a regular expression to match any git read+write URL structure (not just GitHub) and I wanted to check to see if I got the regex right.  This is what I have so far

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+@|http(|s)\:\/\/)([A-Za-z0-9.]+)(:|/)([A-Za-z0-9\/]+)(\.git)?
```

That regex matches all of the following URLs

- `git@github.com:user/project.git`
- `https://github.com/user/project.git`
- `http://github.com/user/project.git`
- `git@192.168.101.127:user/project.git`
- `https://192.168.101.127/user/project.git`
- `http://192.168.101.127/user/project.git`
- `http://192.168.101.127/user/project`

And others like non-top-level domains and single name domains (http://server/).  Are there other url structures that I should be concious of?  Also is there a shorter way of writing the existing regex that I have?

Comment: afaik git can handle _every_ url.

Comment: So I should really just validate for either ssh or url?

Comment: If you really want to get sure, validate if its an url and test, if there is a repository. for example you can test, if there is a file `config` and if its a repository configuration.

Comment: What the application is doing is actually taking in a URL that has read+write git abilities.  Maybe what I should do is accept it and when I actually need to run a git command test then to see if it has the abilities and if it fails send the user back to the configuration.  That to me sounds like the only sure way.

Comment: It seems you are missing `http://user@github.com/acccount/repo.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using rails / ruby to write your program, check this out. You might be able to get some ideas from here:

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/04/validating-the-format-of-an-url-with-rails/

Comment: This is unfortunately not RoR.  It is to be used in ColdFusion.